# Python Bottle json_dumps - pass parameter to default handler function

Tags: python, mysql, json, datetime, bottle

**How can I pass arguments to a default handler function while converting data to JSON using Bottle's json_dumps?**

> **EDIT: I missed a point where I convert the data from `json_dumps`, back to the previous format using `json_loads`. The reason I use
>   `json_dumps` is because i need to convert the `datetime` format to
>   `string`**

I have the result of a MySQL query as list of tuples:

```
data = [(u'user1', u'Topic1', datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 3, 23, 55), 2.0, 5), (u'user2', u'Topic2', datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 4, 23, 55), 3.0, 5)]
```

It contains some data in `datetime` format. And I send this data as response to an AJAX call, in JSON format, because of which I perform `json_dumps` on it.

Now, I can't simply perform `json_dumps(data)` as it gives this error:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 3, 23, 55) is not JSON serializable
```

So, I define this handler function and use it as follows:

```
def dataHandler(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

json_dumps(data, default=dataHandler)
```

This works fine and the output is:

```
'[["user1", "Topic1", "2015-08-03 23:55", 2.0, 5], ["user2", "Topic2", "2015-08-04 23:55", 3.0, 5]
```

Now at different points in my code, for different data, I need different formats of `datetime`. So, I redefined the function like this:

```
def dataHandler(obj, showTime='no'):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        if str(showTime).lower() == 'no':
            return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        elif str(showTime).lower() == 'yes':
            return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Now if I perform `json_dumps(data, default=dataHandler)`, it works properly, considers `showTime` as `no` and gives output same as above.

The problem comes when I try to pass it an argument:

`json_dumps(data, default=dataHandler('Yes'))`

It gives this error:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 10, 23, 55) is not JSON serializable
```

How can I have different such cases defined in the same function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`@decorator`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) ([PEP-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)).

Example:

```
def json_handler(show_time=True):
    def decorated(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.strftime('%FT%T' if show_time else '%F')
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.strftime('%F')
        return repr(obj) # catch-all
    return decorated
```

Then:

```
>>> json.dumps(data, default=json_handler())
'[["user1", "Topic1", "2015-08-03T23:55:00", 2.0, 5], ["user2", "Topic2", "2015-08-04T23:55:00", 3.0, 5]]'
>>> json.dumps(data, default=json_handler(False))
'[["user1", "Topic1", "2015-08-03", 2.0, 5], ["user2", "Topic2", "2015-08-04", 3.0, 5]]'
```

### Edit

The line `return repr(obj) # catch-all` will use the representation of the object instead of refusing to dump it (ie: `"<object object at 0x7f934f6ef0c0>"` instead of `TypeError: <object object at 0x7f934f6ef0e0> is not JSON serializable`); this might or might not be desired.

Do **not** forget to call the decorator!
Failing to do so (ie: `json.dumps(data, default=json_handler)` instead of `json.dumps(data, default=json_handler())`) will result in a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` or `Segmentation Faults`.